# CompressedImage to an Image in a node

Tags: ros, c++, opencv

## Update

Hey I have the following subscriber on Nvidia TX1 board running on an agricultural robot. we have the following issue with subscribing to Sensor_msgs::Compressed:

```
ImageConverter(ros::NodeHandle &n) :  n_(n), it_(n_)
{
  image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/output_img",1);

  cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  image_transport::TransportHints TH("compressed");
  image_sub_compressed.subscribe(n,"/Logitech_webcam/image_raw/compressed",5,&ImageConverter::imageCallback,ros::VoidPtr(),TH);
}
```

And the callback function

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& msg)
```

When I compile this I get an error:

```
from /home/johann/catkin_ws/src/uncompressimage/src/publisher_uncompressed_images.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::function_void_mem_invoker1<MemberPtr, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with MemberPtr = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/johann/catkin_ws/src/uncompressimage/src/publisher_uncompressed_images.cpp:27:126:   required from here
```

The red error statement was:

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225:11: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, ImageConverter, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

I am not using BOOST, and searching around hasn't helped me solve it

Comment: this wont be a terribly constructive comment but have you considered using python for your vision processing?

Comment: @holmeski no sitting on the edge and hoping for some help :) if you can help with a node that subscribes to the compressed message, then it could be a possibility, but my skills are limited with python, but if you could help with a python script of the above I would be truly grateful.

Comment: So you are trying to subscribe to a ros topic that carries compressed images. Once the callback is triggered you would like to convert that image to a more friendly type of image then publish that back across ROS?

Comment: @holmeski all other stuff should be possible for me to do on my own :) I wanted to publish as a normal sensor_msgs::image

Comment: @JTIM - I was in favor of moving the question because you're having trouble with the *software*. It *is* called "Robotic" operating system, but it is still a piece of software. For reference, we have 97 questions tagged with 'ros', where StackOverflow has *630*. I would argue that, if you're having some trouble with the **system** interaction, e.g., you're getting unexpected motion or outputs with ROS, then that's a *Robotics* question. It sounds like you're having **compiler** errors, which is why I would suggest SO. That said, if you're getting help here then by all means stay :)

Comment: In general, as I mention above, I think of robots as *systems*, so if you are having a problem with the *system*, then you should come here. If you are having problems with some other aspect then you might get better answer, and faster, asking on the specific site. Regarding the deletion, migration would have closed the question here and "created" one there; it already existed so I just closed it here.

Comment: @holmeski any change for the help ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Boost is linked against your code by default when you're using ROS. I'll take a guess, you have namespace issue. Refrain from using "using namespace" and explicitly use cv:: in front of your calls. It's probably a name collision with Boost.

Comment: seemed to be an issue with the catkin make file. Thanks for your time!